# Tomcat works but not Solr

Tags: tomcat, solr, war, tomcat6, buildout

I am running tomcat from my buildout virtual environment. url: http://localhost:8081/solr/

I dropped in my solr.xml here:

```
/home/userdir/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
```

contents of my solr.xml  is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context docBase="/home/userdir/solr/solr/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
    <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/home/userdir/solr/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

I could get the solr working  with the workaround:

1. Changed the solr/home dir to point to a wrong path /home/userdir/solr
2. This created error when I reloaded solr.
3. I replaced the  solr/home dir back tho the correct path:/home/userdir/solr/solr
4. Restarted tomcat
5. This unpacked a the jars to my  /home/userdir/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib
6. Solr was up and running at `http://localhost:8081/solr/`

My question:
 Why is it that I need to produce some error providing wrong path for solr/home for it to redeploy?
Why is it not redeploying the solr when the new solr.xml was supplied
How to instruct it to unpack the jars and redeply automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand your questions neither your objective. Normally when you launch locally one instance of solr, you can access it by default through

> http://localhost:8983/solr

If you have door restrictions or multiple solr instances running, you have to specify the jetty port (-Djetty.port=xxxx) on start-up in order to access it.

Comment: Hi I am isolating the tomcat and solr in my buildout envirnment from the existing tomcat and solr instances if any on the host machine.

Comment: Also I am not using jetty I am running solr in tomcat hence my set up. I have also chosen a different port 8081